# Razor view error mvc asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm at the beginner level about `mvc` apps so I would like some help please.

I'm trying to `embed c#` with `jquery` to test a condition of if a user.identity is authenticated on `document.load` but I'm getting `cs1001`(Identifier expected).

```html
$(document).load(function () {

            if (@{User.Identity.Name != "Someone"}){
                alert("Something");
            }
        });
```

Comment: `if (@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(User.Identity.Name)) != "Someone") { alert("Something"); }`

Answer (score 1):

Remove curly brackets from if

```
if (@User.Identity.Name != "Someone"){
    alert("Something");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
@if (User.Identity.Name != "Someone"){
   @:alert("Something");
}
```

or

```
@if (User.Identity.Name != "Someone"){
   <text>alert("Something");</text>
}
```

or

```
var identityName = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(User.Identity.Name));

if (identityName  != "Someone"}){
    alert("Something");
}
```

or

```
if ("@User.Identity.Name" != "Someone"){
    alert("Something");
}
```

The first 2 are C# `if` conditions and are computed server side. While the last 2 are javascript `if` blocks which will be run client side.